# How to reference logo image from different nodes in drupal7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm doing a job vacancies drupal site which has 2 content types, jobs and company.Company has logo image field.I want to reference company's logo image from jobs node view and show jobs list with view including company logo on home page.I've installed reference module and entity reference module but I dun know how to do it.
I can reference company with node reference but I can't reference logo(field in company).

what I want to do is like this image:
[to use the company's logo on job list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDXep.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear on how you are storing you companies. Assuming your company is an entity(node), and your job is a node, You would put an entity reference field on the job to reference it's parent company (entity reference does not reference a specific field on an entity). You also do not make it clear in your question on how you are displaying the entities/nodes.

Comment: Company is a content type and job is also content type.I tried to put that entity reference field of logo on the job, but noting appears.

Comment: @nicehacker Just reference the entire company node. If you create a view you can add the field of the company to have the image.

Comment: As VJamie said, you can use a view to display the job node (which is probably the easiest option). If you want the company logo to appear on the job node page you have many options, one of which is to have a template file for the job node and send the variables to it via a preprocess function. Which option you choose will depend on your project.

Comment: you don't need both the 'references' module and 'entity reference'. Just the newer entity reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this for a project, and I also use the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to do it.

First : you add a field 'Company', on your 'job' content type, from type "Entity Reference" witch reference the Company content type.

You add a display "teaser" on the Company content type, that you'll use in your jobs list view.
In my case, I use a preprocess_node hook in my template, inspired from a proposal on [node.tpl.php reference page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7.x#comment-51188) :

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

  // Add css class "node--NODETYPE--VIEWMODE" to nodes
  $vars['classes_array'][] = 'node--' . $vars['type'] . '--' . $vars['view_mode'];

  // Make "node--NODETYPE--VIEWMODE.tpl.php" templates available for nodes 
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $vars['type'] . '__' . $vars['view_mode'];

}
?>
```

Then you can define your own template for the Company content type and display (teaser) : node--company--teaser.tpl.php. You'll have to copy the default node.tpl.php template, and to modify it for your purpose (show the logo, use or not the title, ...).
You will find some examples and tips on the node.tpl.php reference page.

After, in your Jobs list view, reference the company field, and select the 'entity view' type with 'teaser' mode.